# setting a state hook once data has loaded

Tags: react-hooks

I'm pulling in some data from a session that I need to be able to access before I can set the initial state for the `path`. I've tried a myriad of different ways. It's to show an active state of a link so the user knows where they are, this below works if the page is refreshed but not on initial load. Any help would be greatly apporeciated:

```
const StickyNav = () => {
  const { sessionToken, sessionData } = useContext(SessionContext);
  const stickyNavItems = sessionData && sessionToken ? stickyNavItemsByRole(sessionData.user) : null;
  const [path, setPath] = useState(stickyNavItems ? stickyNavItems[0].defaultPath : "");

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("useEffect being hit with: ", stickyNavItems[0].defaultPath);
    setPath(stickyNavItems ? stickyNavItems[0].defaultPath : "");
  },[]);
  console.log("path: ", path);
  console.log("sessionData: ", sessionData);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {stickyNavItems && (
        <nav class="StickyNav">
          <ul class="StickyNav-items">
            {stickyNavItems.map((item) => {
              return (
                <li class={`StickyNav-item${item.href == path ? " StickyNav-item--active" : ""}${item.pretext ? " StickyNav-item--pretext" : ""}`}>
                  <Link href={item.href} onClick={() => setPath(item.href)}>
                    {item.pretext && <span class="StickyNav-pretext">{item.pretext}</span>}
                    {item.text}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to move stickyNavItems to state and update it using useEffect after sessionData is updated.

```js
const [stickyNavItems, setNavItems] = useState(sessionData && sessionToken ? stickyNavItemsByRole(sessionData.user) : null);


useEffect(() => {
   setNavItems(sessionData && sessionToken ? stickyNavItemsByRole(sessionData.user) : null)
}, [sessionData, sessionToken])
```

Comment: Close but certainly helped me get there. I set the path in `useEffect` and made sure the path was present before rendering anything. Thanks for your help @Polina